# Laravel policy issue, 403 not found for show page

Tags: php, laravel-8, laravel-permission

Im having some trouble with Laravel policies and cant work out why this isnt working?
I have a policy attached to a model with all the regular methods (index, create, show etc)
The index page is working fine, but i keep getting a 403 page not found when going to the view page?
As you can see in the policy i have returned true whether the check is succesfull or not and it still returns a 403

ShippingController

```
/**
 * Display the specified resource.
 *
 * @param int $id
 * @param ShippingModel $shippingModel
 * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\View\Factory|\Illuminate\Contracts\View\View|\Illuminate\View\View
 * @throws \Illuminate\Auth\Access\AuthorizationException
 */
public function show($id, ShippingModel $shippingModel)
{
    $this->authorize('view', ShippingModel::class);

    return view('pages.warehouse.shipping.show');

}
```

ShippingModelPolicy

```
    /**
 * Determine whether the user can view the model.
 *
 * @param  \App\Models\User  $user
 * @param  \App\Models\ShippingModel  $shippingModel
 * @return \Illuminate\Auth\Access\Response|bool
 */
public function view(User $user, ShippingModel $shippingModel)
{
    if ($user->isSuperAdmin() || $user->hasPermissionTo(205, 'web')) {
        return true;
    }
    return true;
}
```

I have added the authorize in the method even though i have the authorizeController defined as well but it still does not work

```
    public function __construct()
{
    $this->authorizeResource(ShippingModel::class, 'shippingModel');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `view` policy method is dependent on a model, but the check on the controller doesn't account for a model. Delete the second argument and only leave `User $user`